# Docker container with it's own IP on a root server

Tags: networking, docker, debian

I've got a debian root server with a secondary IP which I want to use for a docker php/apache container.
Server IP: 80.X.X.X.X
New/IP assigned by hoster: 46.X.X.X

I'd like get all calls to 46.X.X.X:80 / 443 to end up inside the docker container and tried:

```
docker run -d --name php-recent -p 46.X.X.X:80:80 -p 46.X.X.X:443:443 my-php-app
```

that returns
`docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create endpoint php-recent on network bridge: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 46.X.X.X:443: bind: cannot assign requested address.`

I tried executing `ip route add 46.X.X.X/32 dev docker0` before and activated IP4 forwarding `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` -> did not help.

the ifconfing response on the debian system is this

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:*  
          inet addr:80.X.X.X  Bcast:85.Y.Y.Y.  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::x:x:x:x/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2409691 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2995577 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1317423411 (1.2 GiB)  TX bytes:2053704233 (1.9 GiB)

br64      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e6:*  
          inet addr:172.30.x.x  Bcast:172.x.x.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::x:x:x:x/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:165588 (161.7 KiB)

docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e86c:1aff:fe23:b64b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:136 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:36853 (35.9 KiB)  TX bytes:53198 (51.9 KiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:*  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2902930 errors:0 dropped:8025 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2997498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1386678228 (1.2 GiB)  TX bytes:2053792599 (1.9 GiB)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:631737 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:631737 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:252420138 (240.7 MiB)  TX bytes:252420138 (240.7 MiB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Comment: Is there an interface with the address `46.4.43.216`? I don't see one in your `ifconfig` output.

Comment: no there isn't. That is the secondary address that was provided by the hoster. They suggest in their wiki to either "adding the ip adress"  with
`ip address add 40.x.x.x/32 dev eth0`

or forwarding to virtual machine
`ip route add 40.x.x.x/32 dev tap0`

Comment: You can only open ports for existing addresses, so you need to add the address to an interface before running the docker container.